# Angular, services, and module dependency confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting out with Angular and am running in to problems. I'm not sure I am understanding how module dependencies work.

When creating a module, you pass in an array of required modules (that contain services), right? And when you actually use a controller in that module, you pass it a service function defined in one of your required modules.

This is the error I am encountering in my application:

```
Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body data-ng-app="MyApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
        <div class="three columns">
            <h1 id="logo">LOGO</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nine columns">
            <div id="settings-nav" class="row">
                <select class="three columns">
                    <option value="settings">My Settings</option>
                    <option value="users">Add/Edit Users</option>
                    <option value="account">Account Settings</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <nav id="main-nav">
                    <ul class="six columns">
                        <li><a id="machines-link" class="button" href="/machines">Machines</a></li>
                        <li><a id="customers-link" class="button" href="/customers">Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a id="inspections-link" class="button" href="/inspections">Inspections</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="three columns">
                        <form id="search">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div data-ng-view id="template-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- required libraries. -->
<script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/underscore.min.js"></script>

<!-- services for each controller. each are under their own module. these talk to the rest server. -->
<script src="js/services/customer.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/inspection.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/machine.js"></script>

<!-- sets up the main MyApp module and dependencies. -->
<script src="js/setup.js"></script>

<!-- controllers for each view. all are under the MyApp module. these are loaded automatically with angular's routing. -->
<script src="js/controllers/customers-list.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/inspections-list.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/machines-list.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/customer.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/inspection.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/machine.js"></script>

<!-- routing config and main modustri controller. -->
<script src="js/routing.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/MyApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I define my service modules like this:

```
var MachineServices = angular.module('MachineServices', ['http']);

MachineServices.factory('Rest', function($http){
    return{
        //get machine from server

        //save machine to server

        //delete machine from server

        //get machine list from server
    }
});
```

In setup.js, after the modules with services are loaded, I create my main module:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'CustomerServices', 'InspectionServices', 'MachineServices']);
```

There is something wrong with the way these modules and their containing services are created. When I remove them as dependencies I no longer get an error.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your problem is likely within your module definition:

```
var MachineServices = angular.module('MachineServices', ['http']);
```

You don't need to depend upon `http`.  The `$http` service is part of the Angular core, so it is not a module you need to import.  Doing so will give you an error.

I should also correct you on your use of "Services" and "Modules" interchangeably.  A module is a collection of factories, services, directives, controllers, filters, etc that can be injected into other modules to use.  "Service" has a specific meaning in Angular and is more granular than "Module".